# How to rotate block content of fo:table-cell with mendix generated document (XSL-FO)

Tags: xml, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, mendix

I am generating documents for students who visit a course. I have created an application in [mendix](https://mendix.com) and used the document template function for the generating of the documtens. I need to generate name tags, certificates, greeting screens, and so on for each student. On the name tag I need to rotate some text.

The problem is that when [mendix](https://mendix.com) is generating the document it uses fo:table-cell and in that fo:block. From what I know "reference-orientation" doesn't work on both of them, I also tried but it just ignored the reference-orienation setting. As I said I cannot alter the way mendix creates documents and just include a fo:block-container or so.

So my question is if there was a way to rotate either fo:table-cell or fo:block? I searched long on the mendix forum and on the internet but it doesn't look very promising. Did someone already do it perhaps or knows how I could solve this? Would be very appreciated.

Thanks

If anyone needs the generated xsl-fo file here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"><fo:layout-master-set><fo:simple-page-master master-name="FirstPage" page-height="8.268in" page-width="11.693in"><fo:region-body margin-bottom="0.5in" margin-left="0.5in" margin-right="0.5in" margin-top="0.5in"/><fo:region-before display-align="before" extent="0.5in" region-name="xsl-region-before"/><fo:region-after display-align="after" extent="0.5in" region-name="xsl-region-after"/><fo:region-start extent="0.5in"/><fo:region-end extent="0.5in"/></fo:simple-page-master><fo:simple-page-master master-name="MainPage" page-height="8.268in" page-width="11.693in"><fo:region-body margin-bottom="0.5in" margin-left="0.5in" margin-right="0.5in" margin-top="0.5in"/><fo:region-before display-align="before" extent="0.5in" region-name="xsl-region-before"/><fo:region-after display-align="after" extent="0.5in" region-name="xsl-region-after"/><fo:region-start extent="0.5in"/><fo:region-end extent="0.5in"/></fo:simple-page-master></fo:layout-master-set><fo:page-sequence master-reference="FirstPage"><fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body"><fo:block color="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="10pt" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal"><fo:block><fo:table border-collapse="separate" border-spacing="0pt" table-layout="fixed" text-align="left" width="100%"><fo:table-column column-width="100%"/><fo:table-body><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" reference-orientation="90" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block><fo:table border-collapse="separate" border-spacing="0pt" table-layout="fixed" text-align="right" width="100%"><fo:table-column column-width="100%"/><fo:table-body><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="right"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block color="#301476" font-family="helvlight" font-size="54pt" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap">teacher name</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="right"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block color="#301476" font-family="helvlight" font-size="32pt" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap">Teacher:</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row></fo:table-body></fo:table></fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"/></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:table border-collapse="separate" border-spacing="0pt" table-layout="fixed" text-align="left" width="100%"><fo:table-column column-width="100%"/><fo:table-body><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block color="#301476" font-family="helvlight" font-size="54pt" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap">Student</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell display-align="before" padding="0pt" text-align="left"><fo:block white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap"><fo:block color="#301476" font-family="helvlight" font-size="32pt" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" wrap-option="wrap">Company Name</fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row></fo:table-body></fo:table></fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row></fo:table-body></fo:table></fo:block><fo:block id="terminator"/></fo:block></fo:flow></fo:page-sequence></fo:root>
```

Comment: Is there any documentation for the document template function?

Comment: Not much. This is the one I found: (https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/document-templates)